# Date_Format conversion in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I need help with converting Date of birth colmun on MySQL from '21-Aug-1990' format to '21-08-1990' format such that the data still retains dateTime format and I will be able to calculate an age column.

I have tried the following which worked. Now I want to calculate age from DOB.

```
case
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Jan%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'01')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Feb%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'02')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Mar%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'03')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Apr%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'04')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%May%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'05')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Jun%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'06')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Jul%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'07')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Aug%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'08')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Sep%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'09')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Oct%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'10')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Nov%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'11')
when MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3) LIKE '%Dec%' then REPLACE(avb.BVN_DOB, MID(avb.BVN_DOB,4,3),'12') END AS DOB
```

Comment: Is there a reason this column is CHAR/VARCHAR rather than DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: Why do you use `LIKE '%Jan%'` instead of `= 'Jan'` when you're extracting a 3-character string from the middle?

Comment: If the values were being stored as DATE, instead of varchar/char, format wouldn't be an issue :-/

Comment: That's how I met the database actually.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse the date and [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert it to the desired format.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(avb.BVN_DB, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%b-%Y') AS DOB
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried but it's returning NULL in the output.

Comment: @bomotayo - One or more of the "specifiers" probably doesn't match the input.  Play around with them. See the full list of available specifiers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format